# DC geared Motor 20 NM 25 RPM small dimensions.

Tags: motor, servomotor, brushless-motor, stepper-motor, gearing

My application requires a DC geared motor with torque of 10 NM - 20 NM and low speed (25 RPM at most) and a small dimensions (120 mm length at most).
I failed to find my specs at eBay, and Alibaba targets only mass production. 
Can you recommend me certain models of Gear, Stepper or even Servo motors that met the above specs from any online store?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a shopping recommendation. see https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Anas Albakri, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find DC gearmotors on Amazon with roughly those specs.

This one, set with 30rpm and 24v, is fairly close: [https://www.amazon.com/uxcell-Torque-Electric-Reduce-Turbine/dp/B072DTMPBC/ref=sr_1_5?s=hi&ie=UTF8&qid=1511799633&sr=1-5&keywords=dc%2Bgear%2Bmotor%2B25rpm&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B072DTMPBC)

This one has higher RPM, but more power, and you can add an extra 2:1 gear reduction: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01N8YDOC9/ref=sspa_dk_detail_2?psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01N8YDOC9)

That's the smallest you'll find in fairly cheap motors. Otherwise, you'd need to custom order one, or talk with a manufacturer/supplier, which will probably be more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the motor to be short but don't care about the diameter, consider a pancake gear motor.
[image]

Ex: The [AST 9AFG](http://www.astli.com/afg_series.html) is less than 50mm long and has a version can deliver over 10NM at 21RPM.  They have larger ones too

Comment: Thanks for the very useful suggestion! Never heard about this type before.